# Why the button is not working when function is used in another function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning DOM from udemy and stuck here without any hint that why when I am formatting my code and trying to use a function in event listener function value then it stops working.

[image: In the Image when clicking again button after using function is does not reset everything.]

This is the original Code

```
let secretNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 99) + 1;
let score = 20;
let highscore = 0;

document.querySelector(".check").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const guess = Number(document.querySelector(".guess").value);

  //Main Function used for DOM queryselection
  const displayFunct = function (className, message) {
    document.querySelector(className).textContent = message;
  };

  //When there is no input
  if (!guess) {
    displayFunct(".message", "No Value");
  }
  //When player Wins
  else if (guess === secretNumber) {
    displayFunct(".message", "Correct Number ");

    document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "#60b347";

    document.querySelector(".number").style.width = "30rem";

    if (score > highscore) {
      highscore = score;
    }
    displayFunct(".highscore", highscore);
  }
  // When guess is wrong
  else if (guess !== secretNumber) {
    if (score > 1) {
      displayFunct(".message", guess > secretNumber ? "Too HIGH" : " Too LOW");
      score--;
      displayFunct(".score", score);
    } else {
      displayFunct(".message", "You Lose!!!!");
      displayFunct(".score", 0);
    }
  }
});

//Coding Challenge 1
document.querySelector(".again").addEventListener("click", function () {
  secretNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 99) + 1;
  score = 20;

  //Messages Default
  document.querySelector(".number").textContent = "?";
  document.querySelector(".message").textContent = "Start guessing...";
  document.querySelector(".score").textContent = score;
  document.querySelector(".guess").value = "";

  //CSS Default
  document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "#222";
  document.querySelector(".number").style.width = "15rem";
});
```

In the Coding Challenge 1 section under Message default whenever I am using DisplayFunc()
instead of first 3 code lines then again button stops resetting my code.

This is how I want it to be but It is not happening.

```
//Coding Challenge 1
document.querySelector(".again").addEventListener("click", function () {
  secretNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 99) + 1;
  score = 20;

  //Messages Default
  DisplayFunc("number", "?" )
  DisplayFunc(".message", "Start guessing..." )
  DisplayFunc(".score",score)
  document.querySelector(".guess").value = "";

  //CSS Default
  document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "#222";
  document.querySelector(".number").style.width = "15rem";
});
```

Comment: How will others know what is going on in the course, ask it in the Udemy `q n a`?

Comment: you'll have more responses if you create a working instance of your problem on jsfiddle or codesandbox so people can run and see it in action rather than glancing at your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the location of your `displayFunct`.
You defined it inside `document.querySelector(".check").addEventListener("click", function () {` but you are trying to use it inside another function `document.querySelector(".again").addEventListener("click", function () {`.
That will never work.
Move it outside the first function and both functions will be able to use it.
In the second function you are calling `DisplayFunc` instead of `displayFunct`, so that's also wrong.

```js
let secretNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 99) + 1;
let score = 20;
let highscore = 0;

//Main Function used for DOM queryselection
const displayFunct = function (className, message) {
  document.querySelector(className).textContent = message;
};

document.querySelector(".check").addEventListener("click", function () {
...
```